# History of connections to Wi-Fi networks

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, internet

Is it possible to obtain informations about history of connections to Wi-Fi networks? I am interested in past connections, which had been made before machine last power-off. In my case, router's role was fulfilled by hotspots made from smartphones (let's assume that it is not possible to obtain such informations from router). Wi-Fi network card: `TP-LINK TL-WN722N` (external). Below I am inserting an example of what I would like to reach (data size is not necessary for me, that is just my image of this kind of functionality).

```
History of connections:
Foo wireless network, 19-03-2020 11:44, 19-03-2020 13:22, Send: 2123345768, Received: 1627335162
Bar wireless network, 19-03-2020 14:02, 19-03-2020 16:14, Send: 1224385229, Received: 525324143
...
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This command will get you started

```
zgrep "Connected to wireless network" /var/log/syslog*
```

It at least gives date, time, and network name

Answer (score 2):

You can query the `connection` object of the `nmcli` interface - for example

```
nmcli con show
```

will list all the connections that NetworkManager knows about, with default fields

```
NAME                   UUID                                  TYPE      DEVICE
```

Other available fields are listed in `man nm-settings` - the only timestamp that seems to be available is the epoch time of last successful connection.

```
$ nmcli -f TYPE,TIMESTAMP,NAME con show
TYPE      TIMESTAMP   NAME                  
wifi      1584652638  NETGEAR68-5G          
wifi      1504171300  BTHub4-NXMQ           
ethernet  1537710873  Ethernet connection 1 
wifi      1582891130  NETGEAR68
```

Using GNU awk to postprocess into something like your desired format:

```
$ nmcli -f TYPE,TIMESTAMP,NAME con show | gawk '$1 == "wifi" {
    printf "%s wireless network,%s\n", $3, strftime("%d-%m-%Y %H:%M",$2)
  }'
NETGEAR68-5G wireless network,19-03-2020 17:32
BTHub4-NXMQ wireless network,31-08-2017 05:21
NETGEAR68 wireless network,28-02-2020 06:58
```

AFAIK neither the duration of the connection nor the number of bytes sent and received is recorded.

Answer (score 0):

```
zgrep "WPA: " /var/log/syslog*
```

gives information about all connect attempts (including failed attempts e.g. not to our network or after wifi password change).